# linux output show only right of ':'

Tags: linux, grep, stdout

I forgot a lot of my command line. I am doing `cat file | grep "error"` and i would like it to show everything to the right of G:/ including G:/ if possible. I figure its an awk command but i dont know what. I tried `awk '{print $8+}'` but + does not work like i hoped and guessed.

Comment: What's the file layout?

Comment: Hmm, `G:/` -- is that Cygwin on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> awk '/G:/{ print substr($0, match($0, /G:/)); }' file

Comment: That prints the full line. Also i can see you havent tested as there is two ) which gives it an error. The sed solution above works.

Comment: Did you run it?  I did.  It works just fine based on based on your description of the file (which I understood to be "stuff...G:/more stuff more stuff").  The two parens are required; one to close match(), one to close substr().  match() finds the string you wanted to print; substr() prints from where that string begins to the end of the line.  Also: you're welcome.

Comment: Oh sorry. I did run it but i did it wrong. Which explains why i had the syntax error. oops, sorry. This works great.

Comment: I'm glad to know it worked for you. And I appreciate the follow up - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
cat file | sed "s/.*\(G:\/\)/\1/"
```

That will remove everything before `G:/`.  Be aware that if you have multiple `G:/` entries it will match the very last entry.  If you're only working with a single file instead do:

```
sed "s/.*\(G:\/\)/\1/" file
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to catch the text after the `G:/` to the end of line? You are missing a couple of chars in the pattern... However, the leading `.*` in the pattern is probably not going to let it work as expected even with that fix.

Comment: I had to do `sed "s/\(.*\)\(G:.*\)/\2/"`

Comment: @acidzombie24: You probably don't need to capture the first group. This will probably work: `s/.*\(G:.*\)/\1/` (the parentheses need to be escaped unless you are using the `-r` option or your version of `sed` does that for you).

Comment: I copied the results here wrong. What happened on my side was since the first group wasnt capture they werent getting replaced/they were still showing up in stdout.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
  grep error file | grep -oP 'G:.+'
```

Notes:

1. You do not need to cat the file, just directly grep 'error' in it.
2. The second grep uses the P flag for perl regular expressions. The regex says: Find 'G:' and any characters following.
3. The o flag makes grep print the matched string *only*:

   ```
   -o, --only-matching
         Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line,
         with each such part on a separate output line.
   ```